# Itext Add Table Cell data downwards

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I have a code like this

```
string[] data = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                            "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                            "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                            "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                            "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
                            "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
                            "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",};
            using (PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(destinationFile))
            {
                // Creating a PdfDocument object       
                using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer))
                {
                    // Creating a Document object       
                    using (Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
                    {
                        // Creating a table       
                        float[] pointColumnWidths1 = { 150f, 150f, 150f, 150f };
                        Table table = new Table(pointColumnWidths1);

                        Cell cell;
                        float[] pointColumnWidths2 = { 150f };
                        Table nestedTable = new Table(pointColumnWidths2);
                        for (int y = 0; y < data.Length; y++)
                        {
                            cell = new Cell();
                            cell.Add(data[y]);


                            nestedTable.AddCell(cell);

                        }

                        table.AddCell(nestedTable);

                        doc.Add(table);

                        doc.Close();
                    }

                }

            }
```

And this is the output

[image]

What am i doing is Populating a **four** table column using itext not itextsharp.

Ok the nested table is working so far. But if the `data` array is populated up to 100 string of array. I'm receiving an error

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

And i assume that the error is because the populated nested table is too big for the parent table?

So how can i make it adjust that if the nested table is too big. some of the data will be written on the next column. I can't really solve the problem my self so i'm asking a question here.

Sorry for the incomplete question.

Here is the error

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)
   at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.UpdateFirstRowBorders(Int32 colN)
   at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.CollapseAllBorders()
   at iText.Layout.Renderer.TableRenderer.Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
   at iText.Layout.Renderer.RootRenderer.AddChild(IRenderer renderer)
   at iText.Layout.RootElement`1.Add(IBlockElement element)
   at iText.Layout.Document.Add(IBlockElement element)
   at PdfItextSample.Program.CreatePdf(String destinationFile, List`1 lst)
```

and it's pointing to line

```
doc.Add(table);
```

Thank you very much

Comment: *"I'm receiving an error"* - on which line? With which stack trace?

Comment: Hello.Good day @mkl I'm sorry for incomplete question. I already updated the question and completed the error message with the line its pointing to. Thank you

Comment: Ok, for clarification: You don't get the exception for the code above but you get it *if the data array is populated up to 100 string*? Or if *populating a four table column*? Or only for a combination of both? (When you share code here — which you always should! —, you should usually share code that immediately allows reproducing the issue itself...)

Comment: @mkl Good day. I updated the codes. Yes i get the exception error if the data array is populated with too much data that the single column can't handle. So how do i solve this? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried updating as proposed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use an older iText7 version (probably a 7.0.x?) because you use

```
string[] data = ...;
...
cell.Add(data[y]);
```

while `Cell.Add(string)` has been removed from the iText7 API nearly 2 years ago.

To make your code runnable with a current iText7, I replaced that `Add` call by

```
cell.Add(new Paragraph(data[y]));
```

After this simple replacement, your code ran without issue with a current iText 7.1.7 SNAPSHOT and with the 7.1.6 release.

Indeed, a lot of work has been done in particular in the table creation code. Thus, you appear to have run into a meanwhile fixed table related bug.

To continue you should update.